# Systrace of android sdk does not support multiple devices?

Tags: android, performance, systrace

When I use -e option to sepecify a device, errer happen.

```
raise device_errors.MultipleDevicesError(devices)
devil.android.device_errors.MultipleDevicesError: More than one device available. Use -d/--device to select a device by serial.
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using [this](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/tracing/command-line) python script? What's the command like?

Can you try this:
`python <android-sdk>/platform-tools/systrace/systrace.py --list-categories -e <device-serial-number>`

Comment: Yes,  I use the script cmd.   -e option  has the error.   Does it work for you?

Comment: Works for me. Does `--list-categories -e <serial>` give you the same error? What's your Python version? Systrace only supports Python 2.7.

Comment: I had to use `-e <serial> --list-categories` to get it to work on my Windows machine. I.e. the ordering was important.